# Mapping over array JSON in React

Tags: json, reactjs, mapping

I have a `JSON` coming as a response and I need to map over it using `React`.
The JSON itself is an array and it also contains an array and I need to map over all the objects and somehow know the variable names.

This is my JSON. Is there a way to do that?

```
[
   {
      "name":{
         "english":"name1",
         "finnish":" name2"
      },
      "imageList":[
         "xyxyxyxy"
      ]
   }
]
```

So i have tried mapping over it using this:

```
{this.state.imageData.map((item, key) =>
    <p>Device name: {item.name}, En device name: {item.name.english}</p>
)}
```

But I get the error that it doesnt know what "english" is:

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {english, finnish}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

I get the JSON as a response from `fetch`:

```
let images = await fetch(`myurl` + id);
return await images.json();
```

What I need is to be able to map over each object in the list and then also map over data in the `imageList`.

So like in the example above I would like to do something like:

```
this.state.imageData.map((item, key) =>
    <p>Device name: {item.name}, En device name: {item.name.english}</p>
    for(image: item.imageList){
            console.log(image)
        }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? You can map over your array and then for every item use `Object.keys` to get the value of keys of object.

Comment: It is unclear, how exactly you want this data to be rendered.

Comment: Yes sorry for not specifiying.. I edited the question

Comment: Can you include the code for how you receive the JSON as a response as well as the exact error that you encounter?

Comment: `{item.name}` this is an object and throwing an error.

Comment: @AtinSingh how should i get specific values then?

Comment: What exactly were you trying to print `{item.name}` with this?

Comment: Probably the key english and then it's value?

Comment: I was just trying to see if I can get everything.. but the specific value I need is the english part yes.

Comment: Try removing `{item.name}` and see if `{item.name.english}` prints?

Comment: Wait.. is that it.. I have been searching for different solutions for hours and if I remove the  `item.name` I do not get the error, even though the error message was about the `name.english` part.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213230/discussion-between-atin-singh-and-kataroty).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says it -

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {english, finnish}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

You are trying to render `{item.name}` which is an object. If you want to render the object in object structure then do this -

```
{this.state.imageData.map((item, key) =>
    <p>Device name: {JSON.stringify(item.name)}, En device name: {item.name.english}</p>
)}
```

To render the array imageList inside your json , you can do it -

```
{this.state.imageData.map((item, key) =>
    <div>
       <p>Device name: {JSON.stringify(item.name)}, En device name: {item.name.english}</p>
       {item.imageList.map((image, key) => <p>.....</p> )} //what you want to render
    </div>
)}
```